# Why calling file.read in python fills my file with garbage?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, io

Running this:

```
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    exclude = os.path.join(
        r"C:\Dropbox\eclipse_workspaces\python\sync\.git", "info", "exclude")
    with open(exclude, 'w+') as excl:  # 'w' will truncate
        # print excl.read() # empty
        # excl.readall() # AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute
        # 'readall' -- this also I do not understand
        excl.write('This will be written as expected if I comment the
         line below')
        print "Garbage\n\n", excl.read()
    # if I do not comment the line however, the file contains all the garbage
    # excl.read() just printed (edit: in addition to the line I wrote)
```

results in filling my file with garbage - why ? Also why readall is not resolved ?

Python 2.7.3

Latest iteration:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    exclude = os.path.join(r"C:\Users\MrD","exclude")
    with open(exclude,'w+') as excl:
        excl.write('This will be written if I comment the line below')
        print "Garbage\n\n",excl.read()
    # now the file contains all the garbage
    raw_input('Lol >')
```

Comment: Why do you expect there to be a `.readall()` method?

Comment: Can you show us the 'garbage' you are seeing? Because your file pointer is at the end of the file, and `excl.read()` returns an empty string at that point.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Pycharm resolves it

Comment: No idea where PyCharm is getting that from, but there is no such method on [Python file objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: the garbage happened to be some contents of the git .config + the contents of my file (!!!) + NUL etc

Comment: @MartijnPieters: it's getting it from `C:/Users/MrD/.PyCharm30/system/python_stubs/-438294746/_io.py` - duh - ok :)

Comment: Right, PyCharm is getting confused with the [Python 3 `io.RawIOBase` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.readall).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: and here is my garbage: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xd8ya3nep8mis4b/exclude

Comment: Looks like the file was *not* truncated then, or another process also is writing to it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: deleted the file restarted Pycharm still nothing - my pills

Comment: @MartijnPieters: omitting the write() call fixes the issue

Comment: Note that the line `This will be written as expected if I comment the line below` is written *just fine*; you are not printing it because you didn't use `excl.seek(0)`.

Comment: What happens if you write the file *not on in a dropbox or `.git` directory*?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I noticed this (that the sentence is written just fine) - hmm dropbox you say (I already shut down git bash) - let me see...

Comment: @MartijnPieters: shut dropbox down - still no luck - could be pycharm itself though

Comment: @MartijnPieters: added shebang and double clicked it - same story, slightly different garbage (creating it in my home dir - see edit)

Comment: I have no access to a windows setup atm, so I cannot test this. It looks as if Windows is mishandling the size of the file and you are reading whatever random data the harddisk sector still holds at that section. The `w+` *should* give you an empty file, but it looks as if opening the file in `w+` mode, then reading after writing, gives you a chunk past the end. That could be a Windows bug for all I know.

Comment: Ah, found a relevant bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue1394612

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have hit a pecularity in the way I/O is implemented *at the C level*. When you opened the file in `+` mode (write and read in your case), then you *must* issue a flush or seek before 'switching' modes, otherwise the behaviour is undefined. In this case, you added uninitialised memory to the file.

There is a report for this in the Python issue tracker: http://bugs.python.org/issue1394612

The work-around is to seek back to start if you wanted to read back what you have written:

```
with open(exclude,'w+') as excl:
    excl.write('This will be written if I comment the line below')
    excl.seek(0)
    print "No more garbage\n\n", excl.read()
```

You could use a flush too:

```
with open(exclude,'w+') as excl:
    excl.write('This will be written if I comment the line below')
    excl.flush()
    print "No more garbage, eof so empty:\n\n", excl.read()
```

Comment: Ahaha add to this that I am a python newbie and you can imagine the depths of my wonder

Comment: And I just wanted a debug print ahahaha - nice

Comment: Btw the memory was initialized - when this first occured I was seeing the very file I was running in the garbage + the .git/config - I thought I was losing it :D

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: the initialised memory could easily contain data from a file buffer that is no longer used. :-)